# Timer stops counting in background in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, location, nstimer, background-mode

I'm having trouble when using timer in background in iOS 10.3.

It seems to stop counting when device is in background mode or sleep mode. It works good on iOS 10.1.

My app has the get location in background feature and sends to server 5s/time, but now the timer doesn't work in background.

Comment: were you able to find solution for this ?